# Entity Framework GroupJoin Populate Existing Model Not Anonymous Type

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

I don't think I have worded the title very well, but I am doing a simple group join and I don't want to return an anonymous type as most examples in EF show.

Models shown below

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int SpecialId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Rate> Rates { get; set; }
}

public class Rate
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int SpecialId { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the GroupJoin

```
        var query = _context.Vehicle
            .AsNoTracking()
            .GroupJoin(_context.Rate,
                vehicle => vehicle.SpecialId,
                rate => rate.SpecialId,
                (v, r) => new
                {
                    Vehicle = v, 
                    Rates = r,
                });
```

As you can see it returns `Vehicle` and `IEnumerable<Rates>`, I'm trying to find out how I takes those Rates, and populate the rates property on `Vehicle` and just return that vehicle.

I don't want to have to do a `Select new Vehicle` and then manually map across vehicle properties on to this new version. This is a really scaled down model, there are a lot of properties.

Comment: I did not notice about it involving EF here. I think you hardly have a solution here. The approach I showed in my answer is what you should have been able to do but we have to convert that into an Expression manually and I've tried that but unable to do that, it's nearly impossible with my unserstanding. You cannot use `Expression.Assign`, cannot use `Expression.Block`, ... so it's really stuck. You however can try asking another question about that. Finally I would like to suggest that you should use `ToList` and re-project it as `.Select(e=> { e.v.Rates = e.r.ToList(); return e.v; })`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However, I'm not completely following about "re-project it"? Also, if you are referring to ToList() the entire query, I am unable to do this is again this is just a snippet and I am paging these results so I need it to stay as IQueryable/IEnumerable.

Comment: If you want it as IQueryable, then I have no idea but if IEnumerable is fine, then `ToList` is totally fine. After using `Select` it will be IEnumerable again. Also IEnumerble is just an interface, behind it is always some collection (such as an array or some List<>). Also in this case all the GroupJoin is still done on server side, on client side you just re-project it. Without using one-line solution, you can always use `foreach` to loop through the result (as you've already done) and set `Rates` property for each Vehicle normally.